# Entity Framework not populating key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm importing data from a delimited file using LINQ and Entity Framework and in one scenario EF is not populating the key property. The class is:

```
public class BallastType
{
    public int BallastTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The file contains a header row and a row for each entry. The code to import it is:

```
var baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
var seedDataPath = Path.Combine(baseDir, "bin", "SeedData");

var ballastTypesFile = Path.Combine(seedDataPath, "BallastTypes.txt");
var ballastTypes = (from l in File.ReadAllLines(ballastTypesFile).Skip(1)
    let x = l.Split('\t').ToArray()
    select new BallastType()
    {
        Name = x[0]
    });
context.BallastTypes.AddRange(ballastTypes);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Running this code inserts all the entities but BallastTypeId is uninitialized (0). If I add ToList after the select...

```
...select new BallastType()
{
    Name = x[0]
}).ToList();
```

it works as expected and BallastTypeId is populated. One note is that I'm checking this at a breakpoint.

Why does adding ToList cause EF to work as expected? I'm using EF 6.1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a `.ToList()`, `ballastTypes` is an `IQueryable`, and is only evaluated when you enumerate it.  If you check the values of `BallastTypeId` after `SaveChanges`, you are in essence re-running your LINQ statement, and re-reading the contents of the file.  This means that the entities you read when looking for the inserted ID are not the ones you inserted into the context.

If you add a `.ToList()`, then `ballastTypes` becomes a list instead of an `IQueryable`, and can be evaluated multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My understanding is that deferred execution only happens once, so once the collection is enumerated, which it must be for SaveChanges to work, it should not re-run the query expression.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the case.  Should be easy enough to prove - write a function which calls `File.ReadAllLines(ballastTypesFile)` and also logs a message indicating it happened, and swap that into the `from` part of your linq statement.

Comment: Test Case: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6j0PEe - add a .ToList and GetData will only run once, and the two objects will be the same.

Comment: No sure this is a valid test case (https://dotnetfiddle.net/ckMYNk) but it mimics the LINQ behavior I've always seen when querying a real database: the query is executed once. To be clear, I know it has something to do with deferred execution I'm just trying to understand it.

Comment: I think it's your "let" intermediate step in your original question which is preventing it from knowing to only execute once.  In your original question, your File.ReadAllLines is being executed twice (a breakpoint will probably confirm this).